# Cannot configure Laravel API on a subdirectory via .htaccess

Tags: php, laravel, apache, .htaccess, laravel-5

I have the following dummy local website (configured through two different virtual hosts):

`[vhost 1]` https://www.test-laravel.com

```
DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/[WEBSITE-DIR]"
```

`[vhost 2]` https://www.test-laravel-direct.com

```
DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/[WEBSITE-DIR]/laravel/public"
```

You can check it out here through `GitHub`:

https://github.com/napolev/test-laravel.com

Inside its directory I dropped 4 files:

```
index.php
page_01.php
page_02.php
page_03.php
```

with the same content (just to indicate the current file):

```
<?
echo 'You are on: '.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
?>
```

Also, inside its directory I installed `Laravel` with:

```
$ laravel new api
```

On file: `laravel\routes\api.php` I configured the following route:

```
Route::post('/echo-post', function (Request $request) {
    return request()->all();
});
```

If I use `[vhost 2]` with `Postman`, using the following `POST` URL request:
(this case the domain is pointing to the subdirectory: `/laravel/public` instead the root directory)

```
https://www.test-laravel-direct.com/api/echo-post?param1=value1&param2=value2&param3=value3
```

I get the expected response:

```
{
    "param1": "value1",
    "param2": "value2",
    "param3": "value3"
}
```

Then, I want to use `[vhost 1]` with `Postman`, using the following `POST` URL request:
(this case the domain is pointing to the root directory instead the subdirectory: `/laravel/public`)

```
https://www.test-laravel.com/api/echo-post?param1=value1&param2=value2&param3=value3
```

For that I configured the root `.htaccess` file like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /laravel/

RewriteRule ^api/(.*)$ /api/$1 [L]
```

But when running the request with `Postman` I get the following output:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>500 Internal Server Error</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Internal Server Error</h1>
        <p>The server encountered an internal error or
misconfiguration and was unable to complete
your request.</p>
        <p>Please contact the server administrator at 
 admin@example.com to inform them of the time this error occurred,
 and the actions you performed just before this error.</p>
        <p>More information about this error may be available
in the server error log.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

On the `Apache` error log I get the following:

```
AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
```

Do you have any idea on how can I use `[vhost 1]` with the following `POST` URL request?

https://www.test-laravel.com/api/echo-post?param1=value1&param2=value2&param3=value3

Thanks!